# How to freeze figma version?

Tags: figma

Often during development designs get updated and we want to avoid this. Interesting how other people freeze figma version and whether it's possible. We need somekind of snapshot link which can't be changed neither by designers nor by developers.

Answer (score 0):

when you give the link, you have the options to set the permission. change permisiion to view only for other users that see your screens created in Figma.

Comment: If one who gives link changes something, will old link contain old version or new?

Comment: allways the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no such way to share the file version wise. What I do in this situation, export the Figma document & rename it something like "app_design_v1.0_02_feb.fig". 
And then share the file with devs and other stakeholders. Telling them to import the file on their own.

Another solution is to use "Pages". Though it's not very handy for large design projects. You can name your pages as "app_design_v1","app_design_v2" etc. So that everyone knows what they have on which version.